# Lazy load using javascript without data-src?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page where JavaScript can be added into the header, but nothing else in the HTML can be edited.  The JavaScript can be added inline or be an external file - it doesn't really matter.

I've come across a lot of JavaScript libraries that allow you to lazy load images, videos, iframes, etc.  However, they all require that you use `data-src` instead of the normal `src` for images.  Since I can't edit the HTML, that doesn't work for me.

And obviously - using native lazy loading won't work for me in this case since the HTML can't be changed.

Is there any way to lazy load with pure JavaScript and not have to change anything in the HTML?

Comment: The page will load from the src if they're there.  Modern browsers will preload content.  You could try to hook DOMContentLoaded or readystate and remove all the src attributes,  but... you really shouldn't

Comment: You're asking a lot, because usually javascript works on the page either before it loads or after it loads. But you want to modify the behavior _while_ it is loading, so that image elements behave in novel new ways. It _might_ be possible, but it's not gonna be easy....

Comment: In the end, even to bring in the standarized lazy loading attribute you would need to change the DOM by adding the loading=lazy attribute to the img HTML tags, which would be the best way to handle this. If you‘d like an approach where you don‘t need to change anything else, have a look at the polyfill I‘ve developed for that purpose: https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill-with-serviceworker